# Get "Add New Page to Onenote" icon in Start Menu of Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-onenote

3 weeks ago I had a "Add New Page" icon in my "live tile" area of my start menu on Windows 10 Home. When I clicked it, it would open OneNote (the Windows App, not the Office "full" version) and create a new page in my "default" notebook.

I accidentally deleted it and forgot how I added it. I've tried settings, I've tried right clicking "add new page" (you can right click a notebook to see a context menu option to pin it to the start menu), I've tried right-clicking the tile, but I can't find any way to add it.

Googling it yields only results on how to pin an entire notebook to the start menu.

**How do I pin "Add New Page to Onenote" tile to the start menu?**